# creating a data frame with lapply(and plyr package)

Tags: r, plyr

I have multiple data files in which im interested in cleaning up then obtaining means from to run repeated measures ANOVA on.

Here's example data, in real data theres 4500 rows and another line called Actresponse which sometimes contains a 9 which I trim around : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B20HmmYd0lsFVGhTQ0EzRFFmYXc/edit?pli=1

I have just discovered plyr and how awesome it is for manipulating data, but the way I'm using it right now looks rather stupid to me. I have 4 different things I"m interested in that I want to read into a data frame. I've read them in to 4 separate data frames to start, I'm wondering if there is a way I can combine this and read all the means into one data frame (a row for each reqresponse of each file) with less lines of code. Basically, can I achieve what I've done here without rewriting a lot of the same code 4 times?

```
 PMScoreframe <- lapply(list.files(pattern='^[2-3].txt'),function(ff){
  data <-  read.table(ff, header=T, quote="\"")
  data <- data[-c(seq(from = 1, to = 4001, by=500), seq(from = 2, to = 4002, by=500)), ]
  ddply(data[data$Reqresponse==9,],.(Condition,Reqresponse),summarise,Score=mean(Score)) 
})

PMRTframe <- lapply(list.files(pattern='^[2-3].txt'),function(ff){
 data <-  read.table(ff, header=T, quote="\"")
 data <- data[data$RT>200,]
  data <-  ddply(data,.(Condition),function(x) x[!abs(scale(x$RT)) > 3,])
 ddply(data[data$Reqresponse==9,],.(Condition,Reqresponse,Score),summarise,RT=mean(RT))
})

OtherScoreframe <- lapply(list.files(pattern='^[2-3].txt'),function(ff){
  data <-  read.table(ff, header=T, quote="\"")
 data <- data[-c(seq(from = 1, to = 4001, by=500), seq(from = 2, to = 4002, by=500)), ]
  select <- rep(TRUE, nrow(data))
  index <- which(data$Reqresponse==9|data$Actresponse==9|data$controlrepeatedcue==1)
  select[unique(c(index,index+1,index+2))] <- FALSE
  data <- data[select,]
 ddply(data[data$Reqresponse=="a"|data$Reqresponse=="b",],.     (Condition,Reqresponse),summarise,Score=mean(Score)) 
})

 OtherRTframe <- lapply(list.files(pattern='^[2-3].txt'),function(ff){
  data <-  read.table(ff, header=T, quote="\"")
  data <- data[-c(seq(from = 1, to = 4001, by=500), seq(from = 2, to = 4002, by=500)), ]
  select <- rep(TRUE, nrow(data))
  index <- which(data$Reqresponse==9|data$Actresponse==9|data$controlrepeatedcue==1)
  select[unique(c(index,index+1,index+2))] <- FALSE
  data <- data[select,]
  data <- data[data$RT>200,]
  data <-  ddply(data,.(Condition),function(x) x[!abs(scale(x$RT)) > 3,])
  ddply(data[data$Reqresponse=="a"|data$Reqresponse=="b",],.(Condition,Reqresponse,Score),summarise,RT=mean(RT))
 })
```

Comment: So you're reading the same data in each time?

Comment: yeah but doing different stuff to it

Comment: What are you trying to with the `data[-c(seq(from = 1, to = 4001, by=500)` etc parts of the code?

Comment: Mainly delete stuff which I'm not interested in, because of where they occured, e.g. that line you included is the first 2 trials of each 500 in my experiment which are standardly excluded from further analysis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this deals with what you're trying to do. Basically, I think you need to read all the data in *once*, then deal with that `data.frame`. There are several questions dealing with how to read it all in, here is how I would do it so I maintain a record of which file each row in the `data.frame` comes from, which can also be used for grouping:

```
filenames <- list.files(".", pattern="^[2-3].txt")
import <- mdply(filenames, read.table, header = T, quote = "\"")
import$file <- filenames[import$X1]
```

Now `import` is a big dataframe with all your files in it (I'm assuming your pattern recognition etc for reading in files is correct). You can then do summaries based on whatever criteria you like.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve in line 3 of your code above, but for the `ddply` below that, you just need to do:

```
ddply(import[import$Reqresponse==9,],.(Condition,Reqresponse,file),summarise,Score=mean(Score))
```

There's so much going on in the rest of your code that it's hard to make out exactly what you want.

I think the important thing is that to make this efficient, and easier to follow, you need to read your data in once, then work on that dataset - making subsets if necessary, doing summary stats or whatever else it is.

As an example of how you can work with this, here's an attempt to deal with your problem of dealing with trials (rows?) that have `reqresponse == 9` and the following two. There are probably ways of doing this more efficiently, but this is slightly based on how you were doing it to show you briefly how to work with the larger dataframe. Now modified to remove the first two trials of each file:

```
  import.clean <- ddply(import, .(file), function(x) {
   index <- which(x$reqresponse == 9)
   if(length(index) > 0) {
     index <- unique(c(index, index + 1, index + 2, 1, 2))
   }
   else index <- c(1,2)
   x <- x[-index,]
   return(x)
})
```

Comment: thanks that looks good... implementing it a bit to make sure it is going to do what I think. The 3rd line of code is chucking junk trials basically. I guess I can accomplish the same by chucking 1 -> n rows import with same sequence?

Comment: I'm struggling a bit with how I chuck trials I don't want when analysing import, for example I wanna chuck any trial where act response is 9 or 2 after that trial (within a file; 2 after in the import frame might intrude into new files) when getting ongoing score and RT. I think I need to buy some nootropics or something...

Comment: It's quite difficult to cover the various issues in one answer - I think you're better off trying to distil single questions, so that they can be clearly answered...

Comment: @luke123 I've added an example, let me know if it makes sense

Comment: I might try and sneak a last question in bc my script actually does everything I want bar one thing now, what would be a compact syntax to also delete the first 2 rows of every block of every condition(groups of 500) in that function which produces import.clean?

Comment: You should be able to just add 1 and 2 to `index`, so the first two rows are removed. I'll throw in something quick and dirty.

Comment: Added removing the first two rows